# How to prevent URL document access in ASP.NET Solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I have an issue/bug when I type in "https://localhost:12345/Help/ExampleDocument.pdf" the pdf will simply render successfully in IE. I would prefer that users only access this document once they are authenticated and reach the menu point that I have hooked in to display that document/reference on a separate page. How can I make sure that users are not able to access static folder documents inside the solution from the app homepage? I was cruising through some related articles and saw some suggestions that hinted working at the HTTP Request level... but I'm wondering if I should slow down every request to check for stuff like this?

Our ASP app has a `Global.asax.cs` file which includes methods like:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So I guess I could throw some conditions in here to stop the requests from going through, or at least try, but is there a better way to handle the protection of documents inside the Visual Studio solution?

The document is currently located at `Solution\WebApp\Help\ExampleDocument.pdf`

Comment: You can add the same authentication checks as any other page in the website, but once the users are logged in (as in the session cookie is in their browsers), nothing will stop them writing any url that they like.

Comment: Don't put the .pdf anyhwere in /wwwroot, serve it from a Controller Action behind Auth.

Comment: @Alejandro that's not true, you can use location along with authorization to apply specific folder security.

Comment: @Crowcoder Sure, separate folders can be secured by the logged in user, but all in all they don't prevent users writing arbitrary URLs into their browsers, and once autorization is done they can retrieve whatever they're autorized to view. From the web server perspective, there is no difference between a user clicking a link on a web site, a user manually entering a URL or a bot fetching that address, which is the subjet of this question.

Comment: @Alejandro You're correct about how URL's work, but the point is that authorization can be used to control access to static files, and controlling access to these files is actually the point of the question.

Comment: @Alejandro I did misunderstand the question, but thanks for the lesson on how websites work. Such a revelation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you give access via basic HTTP. The old HTTP folder security is the limit of what you can do. This system was never designed for logins or security.

HTTP 5 might have some better solution, but generally you have to:

- Not expose the file/folder via HTTP
- Write and Register a HTTP handler, that will retreive and return the data.
- In the handler you can do every actions you want - including a login check + redirect

Those handlers are particulary used when delivering blobs out of a database. And it might be this is a blob/DB scenario. If it is, you may have some [design decisions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) to do.

But some WebServers also use those handlers for stuff like "download a folder structure as *.zip file".

ASP.Net HTTP Handler might be the most common tool, you never realized you have been using: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307985/info-asp-net-http-modules-and-http-handlers-overview

Comment: you might be onto something here ... seems like if I moved this to the database the issue would be non-existent LOL

Comment: @dave It is surprsingly how many problems can be solved by moving the process to the Database^^ | You could add a Folder for those files that the WebServer can read but does not publish. But really, just moving it to the DB is propably going to be easier. Just do mind the Design decisions you have to take here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion man, I'm going to play around with it today and see if anyone else has any insightful suggestions but I'll remember to mark this answer correct by CoB today ... and until I feel otherwise